# W2K16 AD on non static IP

Tags: active-directory

I accidentally installed AD on W2K16 prior to changing to a static IP. Is there anything broken that I will need to fix? I changed the DNS records for the server but don't know if there is anything else I will need to change or fix once I move it to the correct IP.

TIA!

Comment: There is no problem changing the IP address of a domain controller. I question what you mean by, “I changed the DNS records...” you shouldn’t do that, those are dynamically updated. Simply set a static IP and execute the command `ipconfig /registerdns`. Here’s a couple more details that might affect you: https://www.petri.com/change-ip-address-domain-controller

Comment: I made these changes and rebooted. Everything looks good. I had to disable the other NICs as DHCP was all crazy, but it works now. DNS is working without error but it seems VERY slow. No errors in the logs...

Comment: What is “very slow?” How are you measuring your DNS response time? Look ups to external domains is probably slow because you are using [root hints instead of DNS forwarders](https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln156952/dns-forwarders-vs-root-hints-in-windows-server?lang=en) that point to your ISP.